# a key falls dormant few seconds after last pressing and wakes up when pressed several times

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu

Left arrow key stops responding when not used. Only after it's pressed several times or held down a short while it starts generating input. When I'm using it continuously there's no problem. But once I've left it for some time it gets unresponsive again. The rest of the keyboard is OK.
ASUS E200HA
Kubuntu 20.04.6
Plasma 5